# When creating a dynamic link to maps.google.com how do I add a marker to the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I have a static Google map with a marker that marks the spot however I would like to link to maps.google.com so that the user can look at a larger dynamic map or find directions. Here is the code I have for the link. `<a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=26.097109,-80.1662769">view larger map</a>`

How do I include information into the URL that directs Google to place a marker on the map at those GPS coordinates?

(edit) I don't have enough street cred to answer my own question so I'll put it here for now.

The correct URL linking to maps.google.com should take this form http://maps.google.com/maps?t=h&q=loc:28.834726,-81.328637&z=17.

For a complete list of attributes that can be used in a maps.google.com URL visit this resource, http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters.